# Stokes' theorem for a manifold without boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

Stokes' theorem states that when $M$ is a compact oriented $m$-manifold with boundary, and $\omega$ is a $(m-1)$-form on $M$, we have

$$\int_{\partial M}\omega = \int_{M} d\omega.$$

This is confusing me for the following reason: It seems as if $\partial M$ were empty, i.e., if $M$ was a manifold without boundary, then we would have that the integral of $d \omega$ on the right is necessarily zero. But what if we took a manifold with boundary, and simply got rid of the boundary? This manifold would only differ from the original one on a set of measure zero, which should not affect the integration. This seems to imply that $\int_{M}d \omega$ is necessarily always zero, which of course can not be true. Where is the issue in my reasoning?

Comment: In the case of a non-compact manifold, you need $\omega$ to be compactly supported. Sometimes you need to understand the proof to understand the hypotheses of a theorem.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but how does a compact support solve this problem in all cases?

Comment: Because with compact support, your nonzero integral will have to be zero!

Comment: In case the one-dimensional case helps: If $f$ is smooth and compactly supported in $(a, b)$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f'(x)\, dx = f(b) - f(a) = 0 - 0 = 0$.